# No oauth code in the request (HWIOAuthBundle)

Tags: php, symfony, oauth, hwioauthbundle

I get this error for one of the login API (windows_live) after going to this link :

> /login/windows_live

I tried with also with google, yahoo, and linkedin and it's working for these.

I configured windows live in the same way than the 3 others.

Here is my config.yml :

```
resource_owners:
    yahoo:
        type:                yahoo
        client_id:           X
        client_secret:       X
    google:
        type:                google
        client_id:           X
        client_secret:       X
        scope:               "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"    
    windows_live:
        type:                windows_live
        client_id:           X
        client_secret:       X
    linkedin:
        type:                linkedin
        client_id:           X
        client_secret:       X
        scope:               r_basicprofile
```

Do you have any idea of where it can come from ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, the scope was missing in the doc :
https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/resource_owners/windows_live.md

I had to add it :

```
        windows_live:
        type:                windows_live
        client_id:           X
        client_secret:       X
        scope:               wl.signin
```